# How to use webpack to watch and update on changes?

Tags: webpack

I am learning metaljs and trying to setup development environment. I am following the [getting-started](https://metaljs.com/docs/getting-started/) JSX part. I am having problem setting up localhost server on my development environment that updates when I make changes. This app uses webpack.

Let me elaborate my situation:

On src/Modal.js, I have:

```
<div class="my-modal">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <p>Test 123</p>
</div>
```

The way I view what it looks like, is that I am currently running `index.html` on google chrome (without running any server) - I also have my `webpack --watch` on to compile any changes on files:

`file:///Users/iggy/path/to/index.html`

[image: path]

When I change content from 123 to 456. Webpack --watch automatically detects it. I refresh Chrome, and voila! It is changed:

[image: path2]

All is great but I wish to run it on server instead. My ideal env would be like when I run `create-react-app` -> `npm run start` (`react-scripts start`). In short, the ideal environment would be to run it on a localhost server, and whenever I make any edit on my files, webpack would recompile and when I refresh, it would update. However, I can't think of a good way to implement it.

I have tried using `http-server -p 4000` while running `webpack --watch`, but when I update my file, it would not update when I refresh the localhost:4000.

Is there a way to setup my development environment to run my metaljs app on localhost server, watch for updates, and allow me to refresh to see the update?

Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/IggHub/metaljs-study)

Comment: webpack-dev-server would not the suitable ?

Comment: Tried that already. When I edit my file (I tried changing `"test 456"` to `"test 789"`) and refreshed, nothing happened even though it shows that it is recompiling on my command line :(

Answer (score 0):

Using Hot-module-replacement with webpack-dev-server should auto refresh.
Have a read of this https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

cheers